# Why increment inside function isn't working?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to make function run only one time during runtime, but it fires every time instead

```
var requestCount: Int = 0

func JSONRequest() {

    if self.requestCount == 0 {
        ...some stuff
        self.requestCount = requestCount + 1
        } else {
        println("JSONRequest dismissed")
    }
```

During debugging I figured out that every time JSONRequest() runs it has value of self.requestCount equal to zero. For some reason it doesn't save increment and every time i call the function the self.requestCount is 0.

Why ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Increments should be done using the proper `++` operator: `++self.requestCount`. However, is maybe that code inside a closure, part of an asynchronous (maybe network) call?

Comment: @Antonio That is a personal preference. I agree there is less chance of error than th OP's code but other forms are also fine such as 'self.requestCount += 1` and the much maligned `self.requestCount++`.

Comment: self is optional in Swift. The compiler figures it out. The long form of `self.requestCount = requestCount + 1` is also perfectly fine. Saying only the ++ operator is "proper" is absurd. It is generally preferred because it's shorter and easier to read, but the OPs code is not *improper*.

Comment: It would seem that the increment is working, add a `print(self.requestCount)` right after the increment. It is another problem such as creating a new instance each time.

Comment: @zaph I partially agree, it's also a readability issue: `++` is just easier to read. But as long as the compiler let us choose, personal preference does matter :)

Comment: One thing I love about Swift is all the different ways things can be written, so Perl like. ;-) One problem with this ability is exemplified by the statement: self.requestCount = requestCount + 1 where self is used on the lhs but not on the rhs. It is possible to also have a local variable `requestCount` and then things get into "goto fail" territory. Yeah, I know: Consistency is for small minds.

Comment: TIMTOWTDI : not just for Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that your code is in a ViewController which is being re-created each time (and therefore the count is re-initialized to zero each time)?

If so, you can do one of the following:

- use a singleton - not always the cleanest but it works
- use persistence (e.g., CoreData or NSUserDefaults)

Comment: This sounds like the best bet as to what's going on.

Comment: @rholmes Thanks! that sounds right - I added assigning value in segues and now it works great